# Is concurrent programming more grided or clustered?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I'm trying to wrap my brain around parallel/concurrent programming (in Java) and am getting hung up on some fundamentals that don't seem to be covered in any of the tutorials I've been reading.

When we talk about "multi-threading", or "parallel/concurrent programming", does that mean we're taking a big problem and spreading it over many threads, or are we first explicitly decomposing it into smaller sub-problems, and passing each sub-problem to its own thread?

For example, let's say we have `EndWorldHungerTask implements Runnable`, and task accomplishes some enormous problem. In order to complete its objective, it has to do some really heavy lifting, say, a hundred million times:

```
public class EndWorldHungerTask implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
            someReallyExpensiveOperation();
    }
}
```

In order to make this "concurrent" or "multi-threaded", would we pass this `EndWorldHungerTask` to, say, 100 worker threads (where each of the 100 workers are told by the JVM when to be active and work on the next iteration/`someReallyExpensiveOperation()` call), or would we refactor it manually/explicitly so that each of the 100 workers is iterating over different parts of the loop/work-to-be-done? In both cases, each of the 100 workers is only iterating a million times.

But, under the first paradigm, Java is telling each Thread when to execute. Under the second, the developer needs to manually (in the code) partition the problem ahead of time, and assign each sub-problem to a new Thread.

I guess I'm asking how its "normally done" in Java land. And, not just for this problem, but in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I guess I'm asking how its "normally done" in Java land. And, not just for this problem, but in general.

This is highly dependent on the task at hand.

The standard paradigm in Java is that you have to split the work into chunks yourself. Distributing those chunks across multiple threads/cores is a separate problem, and there exist a variety of patterns for that (queues, thread pools, etc).

It is interesting to note that there exist frameworks that can automatically make use of multiple cores to execute things like `for` loops in parallel (for example, [OpenMP](http://supercomputingblog.com/openmp/tutorial-parallel-for-loops-with-openmp/)). However, I am not aware of any such frameworks for Java.

Finally, it could be the case that the low-level library that does the bulk of the work can make use of multiple cores. In such a case the higher-level code may be able to remain single-threaded and still benefit from multicore hardware. One example might be numerical code using [MKL](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl/) under the covers.

Answer (score 1):

> When we talk about "multi-threading", or "parallel/concurrent programming", does that mean we're taking a big problem and spreading it over many threads, or are we first explicitly decomposing it into smaller sub-problems, and passing each sub-problem to its own thread?

I think this depends highly on the problem.  There are times where you have the same task that you call 1000s or millions of times using the same code.  This is the `ExecutorSerivce.submit()` type of pattern.  You has million of lines from a file and you are running some processing methods on each line.  I guess this is your "spreading it over many threads" type of problem.  This works for simple thread models.

But there are other cases where the problem space is made up of a large number of non-homogenous tasks.  Sometimes you might spawn a single thread to handle some background keep-alive, and other times a thread pool here and there to process some queue of work.  Typically the larger the scope of the problem, the more complicated the concurrency model and the more different types of pools and threads are used.   I guess this is your "decomposing it into smaller sub-problems" type.

> In order to make this "concurrent" or "multi-threaded", would we pass this EndWorldHungerTask to, say, 100 worker threads (where each of the 100 workers are told by the JVM when to be active and work on the next iteration/someReallyExpensiveOperation() call), or would we refactor it manually/explicitly so that each of the 100 workers is iterating over different parts of the loop/work-to-be-done? In both cases, each of the 100 workers is only iterating a million times.

In your case, I don't see how you can solve world hunger (to use your analogy) with one set of thread code.  I think that you have to "decompose it into smaller sub-problems" which corresponds to the latter case that I explain above: a whole series of threads running different code.  Some of the sub-solutions can be done in thread-pools and some will be done with individual threads, each running separate code.

> I guess I'm asking how its "normally done" in Java land. And, not just for this problem, but in general.

"Normally" depends highly on the problem and its complexity.  In my experience, I normally use the `ExecutorService` constructs as much as possible.  But with any decent sized problem you will find yourself with a number of different thread-pools, Spring timer threads, custom one-off thread tasks, producer/consumer models, etc., etc..

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would want each thread to execute one task form start to finish, you would gain nothing from leaving the task half done, then halting execution on that thread and "calling" another thread to finish the job. Java offers of course tools for this kind of thread synchronization, but they are really used when a task is depending on another task to complete - not so that another thread may complete the task.

Most of the time you will have a big problem, that consists of several tasks, if this tasks can be executed concurrently then it would make sense to spawn threads to execute this tasks. There is an overhead associated with creating threads, so if all the tasks are sequential and must wait for the other to finish, then it would not be beneficial at all to spawn multiple threads, just one thread so you don't block the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

"multi-threading" <> "parallel/concurrent programming".

Multithreaded apps are often written to take advantage of the high I/O performance of a preemptive multitasker.  An example might be a web crawler/downloader.  A multithreaded crawler would typically outperform a single-threaded version by a huge factor, even when running on a box with only one CPU core. The actions of a DNS query to get a site address, connecting to the site, downloading a page, writing it to a disk file are all operations that require little CPU but a lot of IO waiting. So, a lot of these unavoidable waits can be performed in parallel by many threads.  When a DNS query comes in, an HTTP client connects or a disk operation is complete, the thread that requested it is made ready/running and can move on to the next operation.

The vast majority of apps are, primarily, written as multithreaded for this reason. That's why the box I'm writing this on has 98 processes, (of which 94 have more than one thread),  1360 threads and 3% CPU use - it's got little to do with splitting CPU work up across cores - it's mostly about IO performance.

Parallel/concurrent programming can actually take place with multiple CPU cores.  For those apps that have CPU-intensive work that can be decomposed into largish packages for distribution across cores, a speedup factor approaching the number of cores is possible with care.

Naturally there is some bleedover - the I/O bound web-crawler will tend to perform better on a box with more cores, if only because the interrupt/driver overhead has a smaller impact on overall performance, but it wont be better by much.

It doesn't matter how many workers you have available for the EndWorldHunger Task if they are all waiting for the crops to grow.